# Writing a Proper Xpath for Selenium: pre Tag Causing Problems

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Using Selenium and trying to use a proper xpath to grab the text from a pre tag.

```
WebElement sequence = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='MFE_sequence_span']/pre"));
WebElement structure = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='MFE_structure_span']/pre"));
if(sequence.isDisplayed()) {
    System.out.println("sequence: " + sequence.getText());
    System.out.println("structure: " + structure.getText());
    break;
}
```

So I've run a few tests and it works JUST FINE for other tags and when that last "/pre" is not there, but when I add the "/pre" I get the unable to find node exception. What the heck is going on here?

Here's the html. Real simple. Yes there's more; this is embedded, but it is the only relevant part.

```
<span id="MFE_sequence_span">
<pre>
1      AAAAA
</pre>
</span>
```

Comment: Your requirement is to find the `pre` tag then or find the tag containing `1      AAAAA` or just `<span id="MFE_sequence_span">`?

Comment: Its to get the containing 1 AAAA. But I need to get the pre tag as a WebElement to do that, so I can get its text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about the tag then. Just find it using `xpath` text based search. I always find that skipping a lot of problems in finding the element. Use `explicit` wait with that since it is a tag independent search and may do a slower search.

```
By byXpath = By.xpath("//*[.='1      AAAAA']");

WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byXpath ));
```

**Edit**

Another thing I can suggest is to use `JavaScript`

```
//Just to make sure the previous tag is present
By byId = By.id("MFE_sequence_spa");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byId));

WebElement myDynamicElement = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector('#MFE_sequence_span>pre');");
System.out.println(myDynamicElement.getText());
```

Print

```
1      AAAAA
```

Comment: No dice. This isn't a simple scrape. That content is variable.

Comment: @TomBurns What content is variable?

Comment: The content of the pre tag. That "1 AAAAA" is not always "1 AAAAA." It's going to be a lot of different things.

Comment: Ok then 1. The text is unknown and 2. `pre` tag is not always there. Am I getting it right?

Comment: 1 is correct. 2 is incorrect. That's why I'm using the pre tag to search for that string - it is always there and always contains the needed string.

Comment: try with this `#MFE_sequence_span>pre` css and make sure to use `explicit` wait

Comment: Tried WebElement sequence = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#MFE_sequence_span>pre"));

Result was "Returned node was not an HTML element"

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a long shot, but try replacing the span by a div.

That is because according to HTML spec, an inline element can only contain other inline elements. Since span is inline and pre is block, a pre inside a span is not valid HTML.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. This is not my html. It is that of a site I have no control over. I cannot change it. So you're basically saying I'm screwed because of the way they happened to write it?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. I'll try and test it tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some further analysis of the source I was getting, brunobastosg is completely correct. ALL of the source EXCEPT that pre tag inside of the span has been gotten by the web driver. However, the pre tag is plainly there on the page source in my browser. Therefore, I'm assuming Selenium is "correcting" the bad html before I get to handle it, thus creating this massive annoyance.

I'm going to assume this is a Selenium thing and look through other libs. The good part is Selenium is still useful anyway for many other reasons. I just may need to use another library for the actual html processing, of which there are at least a few I can check through. Will get back here with my solution if I can find one.

**EDIT**

Saifur got it in his edit. Problem fixed.

Comment: I provided you another edit. Never had to handle `pre` tag before so don't really know what's going on

Comment: This is interesting, but something is going wrong when I'm trying to enable JS via the constructor. WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true); When I do this it is trying to load the javascript from the site and fails. Is there some other way to activate JS?

Comment: BTW, I did not know you are using `HtmlUnitDriver`. plus, as we all know large part of the`webdriver` is written with `javascript`, so if the `javascript` does not work then no wonder that's could be one of the reasons. I suggest you try with `ChromeDriver` or `FirefoxDriver` to see if you can recreate the issue

Comment: Working. Saifur, you have my sincerest gratitude. Oh, and just one thing -- do you know if I can just have the FirefoxDriver run in the background as opposed to having the gui open each time it runs?

Comment: @Glad to hear that. however, a better way to unable/disable `JavaScript` is using profiler. There are tons of help out there. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with `HtmlUnitDriver`

Comment: Actually I switched to a FirefoxDriver as you suggested, and that did it. But what happens is it actually OPENS the gui browser when it runs, which is unnecessary. I was just wondering if you knew how to make it run exclusively through the terminal.

Comment: I did some research on headless with [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/). So far I know you CANNOT use FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver without openining the browser

Comment: Aw. Are there any other options you know of off-hand for a headless crawler?

Comment: GhostDriver is another one out there. Not really used them Just read about them

Comment: By the way, my original xpath code is working now. It was literally just the HtmlUnitDriver. Geez.